# How can I position a jQuery dialog, using htmlService

Tags: jquery, css, google-apps-script, google-caja

jQuery position uses "Fixed" which is not supported in caja, so that nice simple `position: {my: "top", at: "top", of: $("#here")}` will not work with htmlService.  So to move my widget I have to use css and change the position to absolute.

Is there any way I can get the same effect as  `position: {my: "top", at: "top", of: $("#here")}` using htmlService?

or is there an alternative to the jQuery dialog that I could use?  I am tying to open up a simple prompt when someone clicks a button without leaving the sidebar.

Comment: I gave up and just created separate dialogs using htmlService instead of trying to use the jQuery dialog function.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to have a dialog box when you click on a button. For this you can refer to these documentations below:

1. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service#CustomHTML
2. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#alert_dialogs

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have used those in the past, for add-ons we are asked to use htmlService and not ui-service.   And the alert_dialogs also do not meet the UI styling required for a public add-on.